# Implementing snap to canvas gridlines

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I'm a bit mind boggled at this, but i have the problem of trying to get my head around mouse snapping to a grid. Currently I'm drawing a grid by overriding `OnRender` like so;

```
 protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext drawingContext)
        {

            int numberOfVerticalLines = 8;
            int numberOfHorizontalLines = 8;

            CellHeight = this.ActualHeight / numberOfVerticalLines;
            CellWidth = this.ActualWidth / numberOfHorizontalLines;

            double verticalOffset = 0;
            double horizontalOffset = 0;

            Pen pen = new Pen(Stroke, StrokeThickness);

            pen.DashStyle = DashStyle;

            for (int i = 0; i <= numberOfHorizontalLines; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j <= numberOfVerticalLines; j++)
                {

                    drawingContext.DrawLine(pen, new Point(horizontalOffset, verticalOffset), new Point(horizontalOffset, CellHeight + verticalOffset));

                    verticalOffset += CellHeight;
                }

                horizontalOffset += CellWidth;
                verticalOffset = 0;
            }

            horizontalOffset = 0;
            verticalOffset = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i <= numberOfVerticalLines; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j <= numberOfHorizontalLines; j++)
                {
                    drawingContext.DrawLine(pen, new Point(horizontalOffset, verticalOffset), new Point(CellWidth + horizontalOffset, verticalOffset));

                    horizontalOffset += CellWidth;
                }

                verticalOffset += CellHeight;
                horizontalOffset = 0;
            }
        }
```

And that gives the following result;

[image: grid example]

However i'm a little stuck with thinking about a route to take to snap the mouse to the nearest grid intersection (where a horizontal line meets a vertical line). Obviously as i'm using the drawingcontext to draw the lines i have no reference to these lines after they've been drawn.

So i guess essentially my question is, how can i go about implementing mouse snap to grid? Is this more of a maths question than an object orientated control question? I've read through almost every stack overflow question i found relevant but havn't been able to come to any realistic ideas yet.

Note: Whilst at the minute i've hard coded an 8x8 grid, this will be user defined eventually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A basic approach is to compare the (x,y) of your mouse to the crosses by:
1. calculating the start- and endpoint of the width and height of the cell in which the mouse is located; and
2. comparing those two intervals (width and height) to the actual mouse (x,y) to find the nearest cell point.

Here is some quickly thrown together example code to demonstrate the snapping:

```
/// <summary>
/// When left shift key is pressed we snap the mouse to the closest
/// intersection
/// </summary>
void MainWindow_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.LeftShift)
    {
        var p = GetSnappingPoint(Mouse.GetPosition(this), new Size(200, 200));
        SetCursorPos((int)p.X, (int)p.Y+20);
    }

}

[DllImport("User32.dll")]
private static extern bool SetCursorPos(int x, int y);

/// <summary>
/// Get snapping point by
/// </summary>
Point GetSnappingPoint(Point mouse,Size cellSize)
{
    //Get x interval based on cell width
    var xInterval = GetInterval(mouse.X, cellSize.Width);

    //Get y interal based in cell height
    var yInterval = GetInterval(mouse.Y, cellSize.Height);

    // return the point on cell grid closest to the mouseposition
    return new Point()
    {
        X = Math.Abs(xInterval.Lower - mouse.X) > Math.Abs(xInterval.Upper - mouse.X) ? xInterval.Upper : xInterval.Lower,
        Y = Math.Abs(yInterval.Lower - mouse.Y) > Math.Abs(yInterval.Upper - mouse.Y) ? yInterval.Upper : yInterval.Lower,
    };
}

/// <summary>
///  Find an interval of the celsize based on mouse position and size
/// </summary>
Interval GetInterval(double mousePos,double size)
{
    return new Interval()
    {
        Lower = ((int)(mousePos / size)) * size,
        Upper = ((int)(mousePos / size)) * size + size
    };
}

/// <summary>
/// Basic interval class
/// </summary>
class Interval
{
    public double Lower { get; set; }
    public double Upper { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I got your first implementation to work, but was a bit...uncalibrated, trying your edited one now : ) Seems a good starting spot though! For some reason KeyDown never seems to trigger. And yeah, i've attached it to a control : P

Comment: What do you mean with uncalibrated? I have it up and running here and the snapping is spot on...

Comment: Ah really? i was drawing an ellipse where it should snap to, and it was sometimes drawing them over an entire cell away.

Comment: Well, I don't know about the ellipse( which is not part of your question), but what this code does is find the closest corner/intersection of cell borders based on the mouse position when the left shift button is pressed. The +20 when setting the mouse is to deal with the cursor height.

Comment: Got it to work to about 85% accuracy : ) (Was testing with ellipses to show current and snap spot, so could be off to do with that) but otherwise works a charm! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

A rough start to an answer:

```
int nearGridX = CellWidth * Math.Round( mouseX / CellWidth);
int nearGridY = CellHeight * Math.Round( mouseY / CellHeight);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
xPos= mouseX - (mouseX % gridWidth);
yPos= mouseY - (mouseY % gridHeight);
```

This would give you a quick and dirty snap to the upper-left corner of the current grid. This doesn't take into account for if you're closer to the bottom or right of the current grid. It only looks at what grid you're in and plops it there.